Headphone jack not is working on Ubuntu 24.04
The headphone jack on my PC with Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't have any sound output. This is the list of my sound cards:
cat /proc/asound/cards
0 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                  HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7120000 irq 129

In alsamixer when I enable the loopback I can hear noise in my headphones, so I don't think there is a connectivity issue.
